# Submit value as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

```
<div>
   Player One <input ref="p1Name"/>        
   Player Two <input ref="p2Name"/>         
   <button onClick={() => this.submit(this.refs.p1Name.value, this.refs.p2Name.value)}>submit result</button>
</div>
```

This code submits as expected. but i want to submit it as on object. i have tried wrapping the arguments in `{}` but it then complains about the `this` keyword. how can i submit it so the function receives it as an object?

This is what I have tried:

```
<button onClick={() => this.submit({this.refs.p1Name.value, this.refs.p2Name.value})}>submit result</button>
```

Comment: So what did you try that did not work?

Comment: @epascarello i have clearly explained that above

Comment: Show it with code, not just text.

Comment: @epascarello done

Comment: So you did not give them a key?

Comment: @epascarello ah yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap them in an `object` like this:
`this.submit({a: this.refs.p1Name.value, b: this.refs.p2Name.value})}`

A working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  submit(params) {
    console.log(params);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Player One <input ref="p1Name" />
        Player Two <input ref="p2Name" />
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.submit({a: this.refs.p1Name.value, b: this.refs.p2Name.value})}
        >
          submit result
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```